# How to Send ios push notifications to multiple devices at once?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Can I send multiple device tokens to APNS api in a single request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe so.  We use AWS SNS to handle that.

Comment: I am building my own provider api, which calls APNS api. So probably, I had to loop all the device tokens array and make calls to APNs.

Comment: What SDK you're using ?

Comment: ruby with sinatra